# How to have multiple ways to construct an object of same class in python?

Tags: python

For example,

I have my class, `MyClass`

and I want to be able to instantiate it as `MyClass((1, 2))` but `MyClass(1, 2)` should also result in the same. Is it also possible to instantiate it by writing `MyClass[1, 2]` by some way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def __init__(arg1, arg2=None):
    if arg2 is None:
        construct_one_way()
    else:
        do_something_different()
```

You can technically get `MyClass[1, 2]` to work with a custom metaclass, but anyone reading your code will hate you. Brackets are for element access.

If you want to be That Guy With The Unmaintainable Code, here's the metaclass option:

```
class DontDoThis(type):
    def __getitem__(self, arg):
        return self(arg)

class SeriouslyDont(object):
    __metaclass__ = DontDoThis
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2=None):
        if arg2 is None:
            arg1, arg2 = arg1
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2
```

Demonstration:

```
>>> SeriouslyDont[1, 2]
<__main__.SeriouslyDont object at 0x000000000212D0F0>
```

Comment: Love the cleverness, but seriously hope this won't make it into any sort of real-world code! :-)

Comment: @JonClements: Wait, `+2 - (-1)` is `+3` :)

Comment: The English language use of the hyphen... etc... @NPE :)

Comment: @JonClements: I'll buy that. :) Anyway, bedtime. Night-night.

Comment: Thank you for the well documented warnings :)

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do that in any half-sane way. The nearest thing syntactically that I can think of is:

```
class X(object):
  def __init__(self, x, y):
   print x, y

X(1, 2)
X(*(1, 2))
X(*[1, 2])
```

There are some legitimate uses for this. However, they are pretty limited.

Comment: Of course this would work, but this is not I'm looking for. I'm not sure but maybe metaclasses seem that it might help and I've been reading up on them but I can't quite figure out how

Comment: @adarsh then what perverse language evasion *are* you looking for?

Comment: I am looking for something that makes more intuitive sense for representing mathematical intervals

Comment: @adarsh: In which case presumably you'd also want to represent half-open intervals? That would be a complete non-starter...